# ASP.NET Partial Postback Update Panel Hidden Fields Clearing Problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, postback

I have an UpdatePanel and in my updatepanel_Load I have some code which looks like this:

```
if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") 
{
create hidden fields and add to list using
itemFields.Add(newField);
} 
else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" )
{
lookup field values
}
```

The list is declared at class level using:
List itemFields = new List();

The problem is that whenever I want to lookup values in the hidden fields the list is empty. Why is it empty at this point and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class level fields are not persisted between postbacks. Use the Session state Collection to persist values. For persisting controls, you can use `<asp:PlaceHolder />`.

EDIT:

If you are using the `HiddenField` to just store a single value and access from server side and if it's not being accessed from client script, you can do something like this.

Remove your class level list.

```
if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") 
{
    Session["someValueKey"] = 0;
} 
else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" )
{
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(Session["someValueKey"]);
}
```

if you do need a list of values, then you can do

```
if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") 
{
    Session["someValueKey"] = new List<int>{100,200};
} 
else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" )
{
    var x = Session["someValueKey"] as List<int>();
}
```

if you do need it to be a control (to access from client script) you can do

```
if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") 
{
   HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField();
   hiddenField.ID ="hiddenField1";
   hiddenField.Value = "0";
   placeHolder1.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
} 
else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" )
{
    HiddenField hiddenField = placeHolder1.FindControl("hiddenField1") as HiddenField;
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenField.Value);
}
```

Comment: so can I create the list at class level still but make it maintain it's state between postbacks?  like List<HiddenField> itemFields = (List<HiddenField>)Session["itemFields"];  or something? I tried using a placeholder with id="hiddenfields"  but then I got argumentoutofrange when trying to access hiddenfields.Controls[0]  even though I had added controls to the placeholder before the postback took place

Comment: @Jimmy can you post the code you have for `create hidden fields and add to list using` and `lookup field values`. That'll give us a better idea.

Comment: also I declared the placeholder like this in the xaml:  <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="hiddenfields"/>

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thanks for the detailed suggestion. I tried your second method (as I need to be able to access the hiddenField value from client script) .. but unfortunately it didn't work, I got a NullReferenceException saying "Object reference not set to instance of an object" on the int x = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenField.Value); line.  So.. FindControl returned null. :/ any idea why? thanks

Comment: I checked the placeholder's Controls.Count value and it is 0 at the point when I want to check the value. so it seems it isn't holding the hiddenfields consistently over the postback? I am definitely adding a lot of controls to the placeholder before the postback...

Comment: could this be related to trying to check the placeholder in an updatepanel_Load event?

Comment: well apparently the placeholder controls get killed in the page lifecycle. i've decided to hardcode my hiddenfields for now. it's a bit messy as they are supposed to be dynamically generated (from database records) but it will do for now! thanks for the help